# Starcraft II Attack-Move as default "mouse-click"

Tags: starcraft-2

Are there hidden setting in Starcraft 2 to set the mouse button to default to "attack-move" instead of the standard move command, where the enemies are ignored and the units are running blind into their dead just to reach the point on the map, you clicked on?

Comment: "a" left click has always been the way to do it

Comment: To set attack move to left click would kill alot of your own units...

Comment: I'm with Nick...you could easily set up an AutoHotKey script that substitutes hitting "a" and then left clicking for normal left click...but you won't be happy with the results if you, say, select your marines, tell them to move to your ramp, then select your Orbital Command to build another worker. Oops, I mean, you tell your marines to "attack move" your Orbital Command, because that's what left click does now.

Comment: maybe right-click then?

Comment: @Paralytic "t" + left click, if you're on the grid layout :) Anyway, click-attack is certain death 90% of the time, why would you want that? If you want it for scouting purposes, then "a/t" click is your best option. You don't want it as your default behaviour

Comment: If you are controlling your units in a battle (micro) then i think it is annoyint to press A every time. So a macro would be nice. I will try to program one of my **extra mouse buttons**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a Razer Naga or some other similar gaming mouse, bind <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Lft</kbd> Click to one of the several side keys, use that key as attack move.

Comment: I'm fairly sure any mouse or mouse utility that supports button remapping would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a keyboard-mouse macro. If you are using a proper gaming mouse and keyboard you could program a simple conditional like: `IF Left-Click then Enter Character 'A'`

Thus, every time you you left-click you would automatically enter attack move mode if you have one or more units selected. But as Nick122 has warned, there may be unforeseen consequences such as attacking a gas refinery that you intended to harvest from if you are selecting SCVs, although when you mine minerals or gas you usually right-click... but still...

If you are serious about this I recommend programming a macro like the one I described, and testing this for yourself if you have a gaming keyboard and mouse which have this as a native feature. Otherwise, you would need to get third-party macro software for your mouse and keyboard which would need to run in the background while you play Starcraft II.

My verdict: an interesting notion but not worth the effort. If you want to optimize your game-play there are other useful things you can do. I play Zerg and have set my space-bar key to rotate between hatcheries for faster injecting, for example. If you do test this out, post the results here. I for one, would be interested.

Comment: see my last comment in the first answer: "I can program some of the extra mousebuttons on my Logitech to do a macro **Key A and then left-mouse-click**. then I would have the normal functionality obtained" i think that is a better solution

Comment: Downvote my answer then and let us know if you have any success with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there isn't. Third party software just won't help because you need to left click other items in the game so setting up the mouse button to do something wouldn't work. Besides that, there is just so much wrong with having left click be an attack move.

Comment: and right click?

Comment: Right click wouldn't work either. You need a move command option.

Comment: that could be swapped with the attack command option

Comment: If you wanted to try it that would be your choice. But its not a good solution and there really shouldn't be a need to try and find this solution... it will screw you up more then it will ever help.

Comment: so is there a thirdparty software, that switches those two commands? ... and what exactly would it screw up for me if I would? I am a newbie in Starcraft and could never adapt to aways clicking A before going somewhere

Comment: Now that I think of it even with third party software it wouldn't work. Because you would need to tell your mouse to act as the "A" button and then also do its normal right click option. There basically just isn't a way to do this. It would also screw up 90% of micro. If you don't know what micro is, I suggest you learn.

Comment: I know what micro is. Maybe I can program some of the extra mousebuttons on my Logitech to do a macro **Key A and then left-mouse-click**. Then I would have the normal functionality obtained

Answer (score 2):

I GOT IT ! (sorry for reviving old thread, is short and useful)

use autohotkey and write the folowing script

```
Control & RButton::
    Send a{LButton}
Return
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I wonder if there's a way to also solve the no orders to subgroups problem. I really liked Warcraft 3 way of handling that.